# image.getState is not a function (when using ol in angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, openstreetmap, openlayers-3, angular-openlayers

I tried to implement the following code in an angular(4) application
http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/layer/map.geoimage.html

But it always results in an error when trying to launch the browser.

First of all, my imports( both libraries were installed locally from npm):

`

```
import OlMap from 'ol/map';
import OlView from 'ol/view';
import OlLayerVector from 'ol/layer/vector';
import OlLayerTile from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import OlSourceOSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import OlLayerImage from 'ol/layer/image';
import OlSourceImageVector from 'ol/source/imagevector';
import OlSourceImageStatic from 'ol/source/ImageStatic';
import OlProjection from 'ol/proj/projection';
import OlSourceVector from 'ol/source/vector';
import OlBaseImage from 'ol/imagebase';
import OlImage from 'ol/image';

import OlSourceGeoImage from 'ol-ext/source/GeoImage';
import OlAttribution from 'ol/attribution';
import OlOverlay from 'ol/overlay';`
```

Please find the code I used below : (this part properly works)
`

```
// OSM tiles as background
    var OSMBackground = new OlLayerTile({
        source: new OlSourceOSM()
    });
// Custom extend used to position my factoryBackgroundLayer image
    var newExtent = OlProj.transformExtent(
        [2.385083, 48.817463, 2.386024, 48.817694],
        "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"
    );


    var factoryBackgroundLayer = new OlLayerImage({
        source: new OlSourceImageStatic({
            url: 'http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/data/IGNF_PVA_1-0__1976-03-24_pt.jpg',
            // projection: projection,
            // imageExtent: extent
            projection: 'EPSG:27700',
            imageExtent: newExtent
        })
    });


    var map = new OlMap({
        layers: [OSMBackground
            , factoryBackgroundLayer

        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new OlView({
            center: OlProj.fromLonLat([2.585487, 48.817561]),
            zoom: 20, // Set to 20 is better
        })
    });`
```

And then I attempted to display a georeferenced image : 
`

```
x = 274764.75;
y = 6243935.64;
sx = 0.589;
sy = 0.597;
xmin = 0;
ymin = 0;
xmax = 5526;
ymax = 5000;
rotate = 7.44;
opacity = 0.7;

var geoSource = new OlSourceGeoImage(
        {
            url: 'http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/data/IGNF_PVA_1-0__1976-03-24_pt.jpg',
            imageCenter: [this.x, this.y],
            imageScale: [this.sx, this.sy],
            imageCrop: [this.xmin, this.ymin, this.xmax, this.ymax],
            imageRotate: this.rotate * Math.PI / 180,
            projection: 'EPSG:27700',
        });


    var geoimg = new OlLayerImage(
        {
            state: "ready",

            opacity: 0.7,
            source: geoSource,
            imageExtent: newExtent
        });

    this.map.addLayer(geoimg);
```

`

It always resulted in the same issue :

> ERROR TypeError: image.getState is not a function
>      at _ol_renderer_canvas_ImageLayer_._ol_renderer_Layer_.loadImage (layer.js:114)
>     at _ol_renderer_canvas_ImageLayer_.prepareFrame (imagelayer.js:160)
>      at _ol_renderer_canvas_Map_.renderFrame (map.js:183)
>      at _ol_Map_._ol_PluggableMap_.renderFrame_ (pluggablemap.js:1180)
>      at _ol_Map_.eval (pluggablemap.js:87)
>      at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
>      at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4740)
>      at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
>      at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>      at ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:496)

So regarding this report I tried to use a ol.source.Image object instead of url but not more successful.

Has anyone been using this framework before ? Any idea of an ol update that would have created this issue ?

**PS:** I've also tried SnapGuides lines example (http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/interaction/map.interaction.snapguides.html) and it went properly well so ol-ext API integration sounds good !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to the author : https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext/issues/93 :

"I've found an issue with the GeoImage source: the getImage() function overwrite the Image source function. Just change it to getGeoImage() solves the problem. I've pushed a new commit on master branch. If you're using npm just replace the source/GeoImage.js in the node module with the one of the git. It will be included in the next version."

By the way, I add to replace GeoImage.js from node_modules directory with the one commited by Viglino.